# Parse destroyed session after trying to save PFUser

Tags: swift, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

`Parse Server` destroyed user session in `iOS` (`Parse` version 1.13.0) and user become unauthorized after first successful `PFUser`object's saving. Next save (any update of current user) cause a error, `session` on `Parse server` for current user disappeared  and `PFUser.currentUser()` become nil:

```
[Error]: cannot modify user 84Yl7S2mNE (Code: 206, Version: 1.13.0)
```

I am desperate already. How to resolve this error ?
I am using `Parse server` on `Heroku`

```
let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration { 
  $0.applicationId = "*************"
  $0.clientKey = "unused"
  $0.server = "http://**********.herokuapp.com/parse"
  $0.localDatastoreEnabled = false
}
Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(configuration)
```

Tried to disable LocalDataStore - no effect

Answer (score 1):

Parse is great. It was my mistake, I changed `PFUser.currentUser().password` field after logging in. Never do so )